# Would filtering by order ID from nvarchar(MAX) column benefit from fulltext search?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, query-performance, full-text-search

In my table I have a `nvarchar(MAX)` column which holds data about our orders in XML form. Another department often has to get information from the table by, most commonly, looking for a certain order ID in that column but we all need to be able to look for any part of the text in the column.

The problem is that the order IDs and other filter/search criteria are unique to each order and are not words I can define in stopwords or stoplists and new ones are generated for new orders, ofc.

Since the table is growing in size queries with a `LIKE` clause take a really long time, yet I cannot think how my colleagues can get information about an order except by looking for things like its order ID, a part serial number or a piece of text. We have no control over the XML order data, furthermore it doesn't have a standardised structure, which is to say every order type has its own XML structure and there are too many to separate into different tables and we can't extract separate elements into different columns as we don't have control over the processing, only over the storage of the data.

Since an index would be futile in this case I started reading about fulltext search, but would that help because of the reasons I mentioned and if `not` is there a better alternative?

**EDIT:**

Adding example messages being stored in the nvarchar(MAX) column (there are approx. 23 other types not shown here, for the moment):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ServiceRequest>
    <OrderID>GT123456789123465</OrderID>
    <CreatedBy>some.person</CreatedBy>
    <CreationTime>2021-08-18</CreationTime>
    <CustomerReference>INC123456</CustomerReference>
    <CustomerContract>123456</CustomerContract>
    <ShortDescription>A little bit of text</ShortDescription>
    <StockLocation>Text-Identifier</StockLocation>
    <DueDate>2021-08-19</DueDate>
    <ExpectedDeliveryDate>2021-08-19T10:30:00</ExpectedDeliveryDate>
    <ServiceLevel>Same-Day</ServiceLevel>
    <DeliveryLocation>SITE</DeliveryLocation>
    <Site>Address of a building or something</Site>
    <ContactName>Name of a person</ContactName>
    <ContactPhone>0123456789</ContactPhone>
    <DocTypeID>123</DocTypeID>
    <DeliveryAddress>
        <Address1>Address1</Address1>
        <Address2>More details about address</Address2>
        <City>Some city</City>
        <Postcode>LOL KEK</Postcode>
        <Country>Narnia</Country>
    </DeliveryAddress>
    <Parts>
        <Part>
            <UniqueID>168468468</UniqueID>
            <PartNumber>#ABCDE-1234-ABCDE</PartNumber>
            <Description>Example TV set with model name</Description>
            <Quantity>1</Quantity>
            <Returnable>Y</Returnable>
            <ReturnInformation>TBC</ReturnInformation>
            <LinkedDemandId>123456789</LinkedDemandId>
        </Part>
    </Parts>
</ServiceRequest>
```

.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Engineer>
    <PersonId>some.guy</PersonId>
    <SearchName>Some Guy</SearchName>
    <personemail>some.guy@company.com</PersonEmail>
    <PersonPhone>00000000000</PersonPhone>
    <Address>
        <Zip>LOL KEK</Zip>
        <CountryId>US</CountryId>
    </Address>
</Engineer>
```

.

```
<WarehouseUpdate>
    <WarehouseId>Warehouse-name-123456</WarehouseId>
    <WarehouseDescription>Friendlier WH name</WarehouseDescription>
    <CurrencyId>USD</CurrencyId>
    <CostDomainId>MAIN</CostDomainId>
    <NodeId>SSL</NodeId>
    <SupplySource>W</SupplySource>
    <ReturnWarehouse>Warehouse-ID</ReturnWarehouse>
    <IsAutoReceive>Y</IsAutoReceive>
    <IsRepairWhse>N</IsRepairWhse>
    <IsReplenishable>Y</IsReplenishable>
    <SupplyWarehouse>Warehouse-ID</SupplyWarehouse>
    <WarehouseTypeId>ABC</WarehouseTypeId>
    <Address>
        <Zip>LOL KEK</Zip>
        <CountryId>US</CountryId>
    </Address>
</WarehouseUpdate>
```

.

```
<briefing>
    <incident>
        <serviceProvider>A long name of a company that provides a service</serviceProvider>
        <receiverURL>https://www.google.com/some/url/that/is/used</receiverURL>
        <incidentNumber>123456789</incidentNumber>
        <taskNumber>123456789</taskNumber>
        <taskAssignmentID>123456789</taskAssignmentID>
        <taskCreationDate>2021-02-31</taskCreationDate>
        <taskCreationTime>10:32:13</taskCreationTime>
        <sendDate>2021-02-31</sendDate>
        <sendTime>10:32:27</sendTime>
        <request>ABC</request>
        <urgency>ABC</urgency>
        <severity>D</severity>
        <customerName>Name of a company</customerName>
        <helpdeskNumber>123456789</helpdeskNumber>
        <originalCustomerReference>123456789</originalCustomerReference>
        <projectNumber/>
        <project/>
        <callerFirstName>Some</callerFirstName>
        <callerLastName>Person</callerLastName>
        <callerPhone>123456789123456789</callerPhone>
        <callerPhoneType>ABC</callerPhoneType>
        <callerEmailaddress/>
        <callerPreferredLanguage/>
        <communicationPreference/>
        <installedAtAddress1>Address short</installedAtAddress1>
        <installedAtAddress2/>
        <installedAtAddress3>More address details</installedAtAddress3>
        <installedAtAddress4>Even more address details</installedAtAddress4>
        <installedAtCity>Washington</installedAtCity>
        <installedAtState/>
        <installedAtProvince/>
        <installedAtPostalCode>LOL KEK</installedAtPostalCode>
        <installedAtCountry>US</installedAtCountry>
        <installedAtPhone/>
        <installedAtFax/>
        <installedAtEmail/>
        <productSerialNumber>ABCDF123456789</productSerialNumber>
        <productTag>ABCDF123456789</productTag>
        <productSystem>123456</productSystem>
        <productItemNumber>123456789123456789</productItemNumber>
        <productItemDescription>This is a thingy</productItemDescription>
        <productComponentNumber/>
        <productComponentDescription/>
        <productServiceGroupNumber>12</productServiceGroupNumber>
        <customerSerialNumber/>
        <defectDescription>ABCD::ABCD::ABCD EF::ABCD EF</defectDescription>
        <orderDescription>Lorem ipsum</orderDescription>
        <taskType>In summet idit</taskType>
        <customerErrorCode/>
        <problemCode>corpsem mepsem dopsem</problemCode>
        <resolutionSummary/>
        <resolutionCode/>
        <reporteddate>2021-05-12</reporteddate>
        <reportedtime>10:30:44</reportedtime>
        <customerTimezone>EET</customerTimezone>
        <coverage>-ABC-EF-</coverage>
        <contractServiceNumber>123456789123456789</contractServiceNumber>
        <plannedStartDate>2021-05-12</plannedStartDate>
        <plannedStartTime>10:32:13</plannedStartTime>
        <plannedEndDate>2021-05-14</plannedEndDate>
        <plannedEndTime>10:32:44</plannedEndTime>
        <chargeableFlag/>
        <vkOrg>12AB</vkOrg>
        <attribute1/>
        <attribute2/>
        <attribute3>AB</attribute3>
        <attribute4/>
        <attribute5/>
        <attribute6/>
        <attribute7/>
        <attribute8/>
        <attribute9/>
    </incident>
    <incidentNotes>
        <technicianNote>Went to lunch, bought a snack</technicianNote>
        <technicianNote>AB    11.11  11/11/2021
            A huge block of text incoming
            Here a monumental, monolithic, megalithic block of text resides that has numerous details written in freeform however the person doing the thing decides
            There is some structure to the text but it is completely specific to this one type of XML message.
            
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla eu feugiat enim. Praesent malesuada, diam ut ornare tristique, ipsum dolor rutrum enim, et sodales lectus mi at ex. Nulla in varius nisl. Nunc non enim augue. Integer condimentum tempor lacus, non maximus tortor dictum a. Donec dapibus urna nulla, ac tempus justo sodales sed. Cras lacinia tempus lacinia. Sed fermentum libero vel lectus ornare, at egestas eros dignissim. Quisque ac vehicula erat. Morbi id ultrices sem, auctor dapibus ligula. Vivamus vestibulum consectetur ligula non viverra. Proin id mi non ipsum consectetur interdum. Aenean id posuere metus.

            Aenean diam justo, ultrices sed cursus eget, posuere eget justo. Maecenas egestas mi et rutrum auctor. Fusce tincidunt ac purus ut gravida. Proin ac condimentum nibh, id venenatis nibh. Sed eu turpis non sem venenatis posuere eu sit amet leo. Vivamus velit lacus, tempor quis dolor vel, sagittis vulputate risus. Praesent dignissim sed turpis vel porta. Duis elit ante, pellentesque sit amet nisl eu, ullamcorper varius ex. Aenean tortor ligula, posuere sed tempor eget, consequat ut orci. Vestibulum eu aliquet ante. Ut eros ex, dignissim nec accumsan eu, posuere nec ligula. Cras tempor volutpat tempor. Duis vitae dui sit amet diam porttitor viverra. Aliquam ornare, turpis ut pulvinar bibendum, urna eros sodales turpis, sed malesuada felis massa in neque. Etiam venenatis volutpat diam eget placerat. Integer ultrices vulputate neque ut ullamcorper.
        </technicianNote>
    </incidentNotes>
    <ibaseNotes>
        <serialnumberNote/>
    </ibaseNotes>
</briefing>
```

Also I think I deceived you by accident, most commonly order IDs are being searched but we need to be able to search/filter by any part of the XML message, for example I need to be able to find all messages that contain "some.person" in them. I'll go back and edit that.

Comment: Cross post from [so]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68840023/would-filtering-by-order-id-from-nvarcharmax-column-benefit-from-fulltext-sear. As I said on that post, XQuery would be a solution if you stored it in a `xml` column, but we'd need to what possible structures there are. An XML index may be possible

Comment: @Charlieface, yes, thank you, I am in the process of editing that post with examples and then I will edit this one. I also posted here to get more opinions.

Comment: @Charlieface, updated here, as well.